Container in ipvlan L3 network cannot ping its docker's host, "connection status" is "invalid" in Mikrotik firewall, but can ping everyone else
Created static route on Mikrotik:
- destination address: 10.21.0.0/16
- gateway 10.9.0.3

Created docker network on Docker host:
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet=10.21.0.0/16 --gateway=10.9.0.1 \
    -o ipvlan_mode=l3 -o parent=ens18 ipvlan

Created, entered into container and did some pings:
docker run -it --rm --network ipvlan alpine /bin/sh

Ping results:

ok: google.com
ok: 10.9.0.1 (Mikrotik)
ok: 10.9.0.2 (another computer in network)
ok: 10.21.0.2 (another container in ipvlan)
not ok: 10.9.0.3 (Docker host)

On Mikrotik there is a firewall rule:
- chain: forward
- connection state: invalid
- action: drop

To make ping work I need either disable this rule or add another one allowing invalid connection state when source address is 10.9.0.3 and destination address is 10.21.0.0/16.
Why is the connection state marked as invalid?

Would it behave better if you replace l3 with l3s?

@A.B setting mode as l3s doesn't help.
